# JXcore native app as windows service

Tags: windows, service, jxcore

I make a simple echo server that i want to run as service under windows.
here's the code

```
var fs=require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});

server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});

    var fd=fs.openSync('log.txt', 'a');
    fs.writeSync(fd, 'START\r\n');
    fs.closeSync(fd);

process.on('SIGINT', function (par){

    var fd=fs.openSync('log.txt', 'a');
    fs.writeSync(fd, 'SIGINT ('+par+")\r\n");
    fs.closeSync(fd);

    process.exit(1);
});

process.on('exit', function (code){

    var fd=fs.openSync('log.txt', 'a');
    fs.writeSync(fd, 'EXIT ('+code+")\r\n");
    fs.closeSync(fd);
});
```

Next i compiled with JXcore like:

```
jx package echoserver.js "echoserver" -native
```

Then the executable run from console or explorer double click and do its job! GOOD!

Now, with sc windows tool, i create a service

```
sc create echosvr full_path_to\echoserver.exe
```

And the *echosvr* is now correctly listed in services tab of windows taskmanager.

The bad comes now: i try to start the service in several way, but i get always a message that tells me that *the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.*

what i miss?
Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume using a process as a Windows service requires additional features in that application.

Comment: I assume the same... I think I should try some wrapper like [nssm](https://nssm.cc/usage).. It seems to do what i need.. I'll give it a try, then i will post the results

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I downloaded [nssm](https://nssm.cc/download) and moved the one executable (the 32bit one, just to try) in the windows dir, I run from command prompt the nssm.exe and configured the service as explained in the [nssm](https://nssm.cc/usage) link.

```
> nssm install echosvr
```

this opened a popup window for configuration, where i put my needs..
then:

```
> net start echosvr
```

and the server starts! Now it is visible in task manager services tab.
I stopped the service from task manager and the log file was like:

```
START
SIGINT (undefined)
EXIT (1)
```

That's what I need, because it signal a graceful close request!

To deploy a solution like this, nssm offers a command line setup that i will surely use!

(PS: It doesn't support service pause/resume, but this can be acceptable..)